# list aws EBS Volume if Tag ( Date ) < = "Value"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ebs

I have a use case where we are tagging EBS volume with a date once it's associated instance terminated.

```
#!/bin/bash
dateToday=`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`
aws ec2 create-tags --resources $volume --tags Key=Date,Value=$dateToday
```

Now I have to delete all the EBS volumes whose date is 3 days older than $dateToday.

```
dateToDelete=`date --date "3 days ago" +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

```
aws ec2 describe-volume  --query 'Volumes[?Tags[?Key == `Date`].Value)<='${dateToDelete}'] | [].[VolumeId]' --region eu-central-1 --profile aws_new_stage
```

I am trying to execute this but it results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to filter all the volumes that have `Date` tags, then checks the Date comparison.

you can try below

```
#!/bin/sh
dateToDelete=`date --date "3 days ago" +'%Y-%m-%d'`

#volumes that has Date tag
volumes_id_with_date_tag_only=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes     --volume-ids --query 'Volumes[?not_null(Tags[?Key == `Date`].Value)].VolumeId' --output text)

#pass the list of that volumes and then remove volume with null tags using JQ
aws ec2 describe-volumes     --volume-ids $volumes_id_with_date_tag_only --query "Volumes[].{VolumeId:VolumeId,Tags:Tags[?Value <= \``echo $dateToDelete`\`].Value | [0]}" | jq .[] | jq 'select(.Tags != null)' | jq .VolumeId
```

I did not find a way to remove null tags after getting desired volumes usin [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/)

output

```
  "VolumeId": "vol-0a367abcdf"
```